# Hardcoded password and username from database validation

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a project to make a login where the password is hardcoded and the username is from the database. I have a simple index.jsp where to input the username and password, info.jsp where can access if the credential is correct, error.jsp when the credential is wrong and login servlet.

This is my Login servlet:

```
package webAccess;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



@WebServlet("/Login")
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

       try{
           Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("","", "");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs;
            rs = st.executeQuery("select * from user where USERID=?");



           if(username.equals(rs.getString("USERID")) && password.equals("password")){


                response.sendRedirect("info.jsp");
            } 
            else {
                response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
            }


       }

       catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

After I input credentials in index.jsp it just loading a blank space.

I change my code to this:

```
package webAccess;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;



@WebServlet("/Login")
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String USERID = request.getParameter("username");
        String PWD = request.getParameter("password");

       try{
           Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("","", "");
            PreparedStatement ps =con.prepareStatement
                    ("select USERID from user where USERID=?");

            ps.setString(1, USERID);            
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            rs.next();


               if(USERID.equals(rs.getString("USERID")) && PWD.equals("password")){

                    response.sendRedirect("info.jsp");
            } 
            else {
                response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");
            }




    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}   
}
```

If the username and password is correct it will redirect to info.jsp, if the username is correct and the password is not it will redirect to error.jsp. But if the username is not valid and the password is correct and not correct, it will load a blank space.

Comment: You're redirecting to `index.jsp` instead of `error.jsp` in case the credentials are wrong.

Comment: where does the page get redirected to if there is an exception?  Also, you should not stored the password in plaintext in your DB

Comment: A hardcoded password? What could *possibly* go wrong? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code and query should be modified like below:

select password from user where USERID=?

```
while(rs.next()) {
   if(password.equals(rs.getString("password"))){
        response.sendRedirect("info.jsp");
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");
   }
}
```